# Create pipeline from screwdriver UI

Tags: screwdriver-cd

I am using docker container to bring up screwdriver UI on local machine.

Able to bring up docker image for screwdriver UI as mentioned in below documentation
https://docs.screwdriver.cd/cluster-management/configure-ui

On sigin in to screwdriver UI http://localhost:8000/create, clicking on SCM its redirecting to another page "http://localhost:8000/nil/v4/auth/login/web", this URL has nil. Closing this subscreen takes control back to main screen to create pipeline.

I believe i need to add GitHub token or some authentication mechanism in my local screwdriver configs. This configs are not mentioned in the documentation. Is there anything i am missing to update any configs, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the SCM config in the docker-compose.yaml file generated as aprt of in-a-box set up. It goes like this

```
services:
    api:
        environment:
            SCM_SETTINGS: |
                {
                    "github": {
                        "plugin": "github",
                        "config": {"username": "sd-buildbot", "secret": "SUPER-SECRET-SIGNING-THING", "oauthClientSecret": "MY_OATH_SECRET", "email": "dev-null@screwdriver.cd", "oauthClientId": "MY_OATH_CLIENT_ID"}
                    }
                }
```